# Creating a rule for a printable character in lex/yacc

Tags: regex, parsing, compilation, bison, flex-lexer

I would like to create a grammar rule for a printable character (any character which returns `true` using C `isprint()` function.

For this purpose i created the following regex rule inside my lex file:

```
[\x20-\x7E] { yylval.ch = strdup(yytext); return CHARACTER; }
```

The regular expression contains all the printable characters based on their ASCII hexadecimal value.

On my first attempt this rule was located in the bottom, but any printable character that was already stated before obviously wasn't included, for example if my input was the character `'+'` and i had a previous rule:

```
"+" { return PLUS_OPERATOR; }
```

The parser accepted it as a `PLUS_OPERATOR` and not as `CHARACTER`.

Than i tried to place the character rule on top of my scanner, and from the same reason as before - all the following rules with characters in the printable range could not be matched.

My question is what can i do to create a rule that will match all printable characters but also rules for specific characters.

The only thing that i can think of is to putt it on the bottom and use a grammar rule with all one-character regular expression rules and the character rule (ex. `CHAR : PLUS_OPERATOR | MINUS_OPERATOR | EQUAL_OPERATOR | CHARACTER`)

I have a lot more than 3 one character rules in my lex file so obviously i'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Well, do you want PLUS _OPERATOR or not? It's up to you. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly. The lexer selects exactly one token value, and you seem to understand how to order the file to decide which rule wins. What else do you want?

Comment: @rici Sorry for the unclarity of my question, I'm looking for a way to define a grammar rule in my scanner for a printable character, but also define rules based on specific characters that are printable. Look at the example in the end, that but in an elegant way.

Comment: Again, you need to make up your mind. Either `+` is a PLUS_OPERATOR in your grammar *or* it is a CHAR. It can't be both at the same time. There are ways of making it both at *different* times, by using start conditions, but that doesn't appear to be what you're asking for.

Comment: @EJP well in that case I would like the parser/scanner start "thinking" of it as a printable character only when it's surrounded by single quotes, is that possible?

Comment: Of course, just a rule `'+' {...}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is the one you propose: create a non-terminal which is the union of all the relevant terminals.

Personally, I find grammars much more readable if single-character tokens are written as themselves, so I would write:

```
printable: '+' | '-' | '=' | CHAR
```

in the bison file, and in the scanner:

```
[-+=]        { yylval.ch = yytext[0]; return yylval.ch; } 
[[:print:]]  { yylval.ch = yytext[0]; return CHAR; }
```

(which in turn requires the semantic type to be a union with both char and char* fields; the advantage is that you don't need to worry about freeing the strings created for operator characters.)

That is about as elegant as it gets, I'm afraid.